# How to recover files?

Tags: file

I was editing a code in raspberry with the nano editor and I accidentally turned off the raspberry and now when I opened the file, there is nothing, any idea of how to recover the code?

Comment: what does running "ls -la" in the folder containing the file show for file size? If it appears to still contain code(not 0 bytes) you can "cat filename" to print the file out and see what it contains.   If its actually gone, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Restore the file from your last backup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at [the solutions here](https://serverfault.com/questions/453703/can-i-recover-a-nano-process-from-a-previous-terminal) but they are quite advanced and I would say there's little chance of recovery unless you get quite lucky.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, sadly I tried them all, but I think I will start rewriting, thanks!